# install lispbuilder-sdl on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sdl, common-lisp, sdl-2

anyone develop common lisp games on Mac OS X? Recently, I want to set up a lisp games development on Mac OS X. But I get stuck.

```
Operating System version: 
    ProductName:    Mac OS X
    ProductVersion: 10.11.4
    BuildVersion:   15E65

sbcl version: 
    SBCL 1.3.3
```

I find the Github repository page: https://github.com/lispbuilder/lispbuilder/wiki/DownloadInstallation and follow the OS X installation part. I tried to install Runtime Libraries of SDL 1.2 and Runtime Binaries as well as Development Libraries of SDL 2.0. It behaves as the following:

when I run some simple code which runs well on Linux that uses lispbuilder-sdl:

```
(defun draw-a-box-in-window ()
(sdl:with-init
  ()
(let ((width 500)
      (height 500))
  (sdl:window width height)
  (setf (sdl:frame-rate) 60)
  (sdl:clear-display
   (sdl:color
    :r 127
    :g 127
    :b 127))
  (sdl:draw-box
   (sdl:rectangle
    :x (floor (/ width 3))
    :y (floor (/ height 3))
    :w (floor (/ height 3))
    :h (floor (/ height 3)))
   :color (sdl:color
           :r 200
           :g 200
           :b 200))
  (sdl:update-display)
  (sdl:with-events
      ()
    (:quit-event () t)
    (:key-down-event ()
                     (when (sdl:key-down-p :sdl-key-q)
                       (sdl:push-quit-event)))))))
(draw-a-box-in-window)
```

something errors happened:

```
arithmetic error FLOATING-POINT-INEXACT signalled
[Condition of type FLOATING-POINT-INEXACT]

Restarts:
0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME evaluation request.
1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "worker" RUNNING {1005D039E3}>)

Backtrace:
0: ("bogus stack frame")
1: ("foreign function: -[NSPlaceholderNumber initWithDouble:]")
2: ("foreign function: +[CALayer defaultValueForKey:]")
```

Anyone knows how to solve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @aries_liuxueyangm, I propose to you this solution.

```
(ql:quickload 'lispbuilder-sdl)

(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :lispbuilder-sdl)
(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :cocoahelper)

(defparameter *random-color* sdl:*white*)

(defun draw-a-box-in-window ()
(sdl:with-init
  ()
(let ((width 500)
      (height 500))
  (sdl:window width height)
  (setf (sdl:frame-rate) 60)
  (sdl:clear-display
   (sdl:color
    :r 127
    :g 127
    :b 127))
  (sdl:draw-box
   (sdl:rectangle
    :x (floor (/ width 3))
    :y (floor (/ height 3))
    :w (floor (/ height 3))
    :h (floor (/ height 3)))
   :color (sdl:color
           :r 200
           :g 200
           :b 200))
  (sdl:update-display)
  (sdl:with-events
      ()
    (:quit-event () t)
    (:key-down-event ()
                     (when (sdl:key-down-p :sdl-key-q)
                       (sdl:push-quit-event)))))))


(defun main (argv &aux (argc (length argv)))
  (draw-a-box-in-window)
)

(sb-int:with-float-traps-masked (:invalid :inexact :overflow) (main *posix-argv*))
```

Comment: This works. Thank you so much! Though something strange happens sometimes.

Comment: @aries if it worked you should mark the answer as correct. This gives the answer-er their well deserved karma

Comment: @Baggers thanks for your suggestion. I marked it just now.